# How to export file properties as markdown properties in orgmode?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

Say I have an org file as such:

```
#+EXCLUDE_TAGS: noexport
#+TITLE: Cool Title
#+AUTHOR: Cool Author
#+EMAIL: Cool Email
#+OPTIONS: prop:t toc:nil todo:nil
#+SUMMARY: this is the summary
#+TAGS: ['markdown', 'code', 'features']
* Title
description about things
```

Is there a way to export this to markdown so that I get the properties at the top of the file as such:

```
___
title: Cool Title
tags: ['markdown', 'code', 'features']
author: Cool Author
exclude_tags: noexport
options: prop:t toc:nil todo:nil
summary: this is a summary
___
# Title
description about things
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(org-md-headline-style 'meta))
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question.